# NuGet Install Packages with -source parameter isn't downloading nuget.org

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

My company hosts our own internal NuGet package repository for us to upload our own private, proprietary packages to. We still use the official NuGet.org repository for pulling down all the public packages. We also enable [Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) in our projects to allow our build to download missing packages.

We have added our own NuGet repo to the list in `Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources` and we have also left the default one ([NuGet official package source](https://nuget.org/api/v2/)) in the list as well. We also have our own repo in the `NuGet.targets` file as a `PackageSource` element. The offical repo is **not** included as a `PackageSource` in that file though.

This has worked for us for several months. When we release new version of our own packages to our repo, they are visible to the projects. Also, when new public packages become available, our projects haven't had any problems finding them on [nuget.org](http://nuget.org/).

Just recently however, the build has started failing to download packages from the official repo. When I build the solution, the output contains the following line for every project which references missing packages we aren't hosting on our own repo:

```
C:\code\MyCodebase\.nuget\nuget.targets(79,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\code\MyCodebase\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\code\MyCodebase\MyProject\packages.config" -source "http://nuget.example.com/repo/" -o "C:\code\MyCodebase\packages"" exited with code -1.
```

If I run that command from the command line myself, I see this output in bright red:

```
Unable to find version '2.5.10.11092' of package 'NUnit'.
Unable to find version '1.2.0' of package 'Common.Logging'.
```

I assume this is happening because our repo doesn't contain any NUnit packages and the `-Source` parameter isn't using the official repo.

My question is: Why did it used to work? Am I crazy? Or has something in the `NuGet.exe` behavior changed in a recent update? I was under the impression that NuGet **always** used the official repo as a final fallback and it seemed that way up until yesterday.

Is the only solution to add the official NuGet repo into the `NuGet.targets` file? What is the best way to handle having private and public package dependencies in the same solution? I would like to avoid having to upload all the public packages we use to our own repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment in nuget.target states the following, you need to add the official feed to the list 

<!-- Package sources used to restore packages. By default, registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config will be used -->
       
 <!-- The official NuGet package source (https://nuget.org/api/v2/) will be excluded if package sources are specified and it does not appear in the list -->

Did you recently clear your nuget cache from %appdata%\local\nuget\cache? When I tried the steps on my box it worked installing the dependency if the missing package (from the local repo) is in the local nuget cache.

Comment: I do not see that second `<!--` comment in my `NuGet.targets` file because (I assume) mine was generated off an older version of the file. I have not cleared my cache ever. I did upgrade NuGet a couple weeks ago and I have (more) recently wiped out my Solution's `packages` folder. I am guessing that they just recently changed NuGet to force you to include the Official repo explicitely and I hadn't cleared my `packages` folder since then... until now. The solution seems to be that you have to explicitly reference the Official repo as a PackageSource. Thanks!

Comment: For future readers, on my Windows 7 x64 machine, the nuget cache was at            %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\